# ¿ Cuál es el objetivo de usar bind(this) en un método en JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-2015

¿Por qué en el método `filter` tengo que usar `.bind(this)` como sigue: `onChange={this.filter.bind(this)}`, en vez de solo usar el método `filter` sin `.bind(this)` como en `onChange={this.filter}`?

```
export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
  filter(event) {
    this.props.store.filter = event.target.value
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>toDos</h1>
      <input className="filter" onChange={this.filter.bind(this)} />

    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eso es una restricción de javascript, debido a que el parámetro que pasas al event handler `onChange` puede venir desde cualquier fuente y no necesariamente desde el componente actual. Pon el siguiente ejemplo en que la función `filter` está definida en un componente que usa a  `TodoList`:

```
export default class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  filter(event) {
    this.props.store.filter = event.target.value
  }

  render() {
    return 
      <div>
        <TodoList filter={this.filter} />
      </div>
  }
}


export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { filter } = this.props
    return 
      <div>
        <h1>toDos</h1>
        <input className="filter" onChange={filter} />
      </div>
  }
}
```

¿Cual debería ser para este caso, dentro del contexto de la función `filter`, el valor de `this`? ¿El componente `TodoApp` o `TodoList`?
Por tanto ES6 te fuerza a especificar manualmente cual será el contexto para `this`. Para el ejemplo descrito, si quisieras que `this` fuese `TodoApp` usarías:

```
        <TodoList filter={this.filter.bind(this)} />
```

Y si quisieras que fuese `TodoList`, usarías:

```
        <input className="filter" onChange={filter.bind(this)} />
```

Una forma más limpia de realizar esto es definir los `bind` dentro del constructor del componente, en vez de hacerlo inline:

```
export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.filter = this.filter.bind(this);
  }

  filter(event) {
    this.props.store.filter = event.target.value
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>toDos</h1>
      <input className="filter" onChange={this.filter} />

    </div>
  }
}
```

Otra forma, que puedes encontrarte en varios ejemplos de react en internet, es usando `React.createClass`, la cual internamente trae algo de azúcar sintáctica para evitarte hacer los `bind` por tu cuenta:

```
const TodoList = React.createClass({
  filter(event) {
    this.props.store.filter = event.target.value
  },

  render() {
    return 
      <div>
        <h1>toDos</h1>
        <input className="filter" onChange={this.filter} />
      </div>
  }
});

export default TodoList;
```

Ojo que aquí se está usando ES5, a diferencia de cuando extiendes tu clase desde `React.Component` que es ES6. A pesar de que en el fondo hacen lo mismo, existen otras diferencias sutiles entre ambas, las que puedes consultar en [éste artículo](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/).

Una última opción sería usar un arrow `=>` de ES6, el cual hace un `bind(this)` internamente:

```
export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
  filter = (event) => {
    this.props.store.filter = event.target.value
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>toDos</h1>
      <input className="filter" onChange={this.filter} />

    </div>
  }
}
```

sin embargo, si pretendes pasar parámetros a tu función (por ejemplo `onChange={this.filter('name')}` , deberás tener una precaución extra con el operador `=>`. Tu función debería ser como sigue:

```
export default class TodoList extends React.Component {
  filter = (element) => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.store.filter = element;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>toDos</h1>
      <input className="filter" onChange={this.filter('name')} />

    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: .@Alter Lagos, como se llama el patrón que estas mencionando en el último ejemplo `filter = (element) => (event) => {...}`, es una función tras otra y estoy estudiando el concepto de **Higer Order Functions/Components** que es donde lo he visto hasta ahora, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En ES6 existe el operador Arrow que te permite 'bindear' 'this' (Contexto de ejecución inmediatamente superior) de forma mas natural en lugar de hacerlo manualmente en el constructor.

```
export default class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    filter = (event) => {
        this.props.store.filter = event.target.value
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TodoList filter={this.filter} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Adicionalmente no es una restricción de ES6, el problema lo puedes observar en anteriores versiones al igual que la función bind() que esta definida en el prototype.

La mejora sintáctica es la introducida por ES6 con el operador Arrow mencionado anteriormente, React hace el trabajo por ti de asignar la clase como valor a la palabra reservada 'this' por ti únicamente en las funciones definidas en React.Component como las funciones render, componentDidMount etc., sin embargo si defines tus propias funciones en la clase hija de React.Component tienes que establecer el valor de 'this' por cada función manualmente utilizando el operador Arrow.

Adicionalmente debes entender que en javascript 'this' funciona diferente a otros lenguajes, en javascript 'this' toma el valor del contexto de ejecución inmediatamente superior y no el de la clase por esta razón this no siempre tomara el valor de clase donde defines la función y tienes que establecerlo manualmente.