# Uso de ref en react, Cannot read property 'textInput' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy desarrollando un formulario de registro con React y quiero usar ref, sin envargo siempre me muestra un error en que esta no se puede leer.
 - Cannot read property 'textInput' of undefined.

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './Registro.css';


export default class Registro extends Component {

  textInput = React.createRef();
  inputPasswordRef = React.createRef();
  inputPasswordConfirmRef = React.createRef();
  
  .......
   imprimir(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    const email = this.textInput;
    console.log(email);
  }
  ..........
  
  render() {
        return (
          <div className="login-block">
             <input type="text" className="form-control username" ref={this.textInput} placeholder="Email" autoComplete="username"  /> 
             
             .........
             
  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success float-right" onClick={this.imprimir} >Registrarme</button>
```

Comment: al intentar leerlo tambien he usado  `const email = this.textInput.current.value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo dos opciones, una que uses `onClick={this.imprimir.bind(this)}` para pasar como referencia el contexto de `this` a tu función.
Lo otro es que definas tu función como

```
imprimir = (e) => {
```

más información sobre el por qué de esto, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/40937/213). Saludos

Comment: Te agradezco , si , manejar arrow funtion fue la solucion mas practica, aun no entiendo por que el contexto se pierde, averiguaré ...