# ¿Como enviar props a un componente en react con condicional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aplicación-web

Estoy tratando de pasar una prop a un comopnente hijo en react, solo si este cumple con unas condiciones.

Se que se puede hacer un tipo de condicional para enviar props de esta manera:

```js
<ComponenteEjemplo

propCondicional={
(this.state.infoEjemplo1 === 'una cadena de estring cualquiera') ? this.state.infoEjemplo1 : null
}

/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Pero yo necesito hacer mas validaciones, hasta ahora esto es lo que tengo:

```js
<ComponenteEjemplo

propsCondicional={ 
  (this.props.channel && this.props.some) ?  
    (this.props.some.conv && (this.props.some.conv.id === this.props.channel.conv.id) ? 
        this.props.channel :''
    (this.state.contentId === this.props.channel)? this.props.channel:''
): null

}

/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Me explico,  lo que quiero hacer es:
si channel y some existen se pase a validar dos posibles casos:
si some.conv existe y ademas some.conv.id es === channel.conv.id ? entonces se debe pasar como prop channel.

Si eso es falso y existe contentId y ademas es exactamente igual a channel entonces se pasa channel.

Si ninguno de esos casos es verdad se debe pasar un null o un string vacio '' (no tengo problema con cualquiera de los dos)

No estoy muy seguro de que lo que hice sea correcto y de lo que si estoy seguro es que no es la mejor forma de llevarlo a cabo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En general es muy mala práctica ocupar operadores ternarios anidados, principalmente porque por ahorrarte algunas lineas, dejas un código difícil de leer. Para tu caso, creo que lo mejor es que muevas la lógica a una nueva función:

```
tuFuncion() {
  const { channel, some } = this.props;
  // Validando que campos vengan poblados con una condicional guardia
  if (!channel || !channel.conv || !some || !some.conv) {
    return; // O retorna un string vacio, como tu quieras
  }
  const { contentId } = this.state;
  // Para ambas condiciones, lo que retornas es channel, así que se puede
  // simplificar todo a un simple if.
  if (some.conv.id === channel.conv.id || contentId === channel) {
    return channel;
  }
  // Lo que no pase los if, aquí retornará null implicitamente
}
```

*Ojo con la comparación de `contentId === channel`, ya que `channel` claramente es un objeto, mientras que `contentId` podría ser un simple numero o string. Incluso si `contentId` es un objeto, no debería ser posible la comparación entre ellos. Ahí tu conoces mejor que nadie cuál es la lógica que debería aplicar*
Luego, para llamar la función, usas:

```
<ComponenteEjemplo propsCondicional={this.tuFuncion.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: Tienes mucha razón, muchas gracias.... Y si, lo de contentId === channel es verdad, se me olvidó escribirlo bien; debería ser contentId === channel.conv.id, ya que ambos son un string

Comment: Tengo una pregunta ¿Porque debo utilizar .bind(this) para llamar la función?

Comment: @Ale te dejo [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40917/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-objetivo-de-usar-bindthis-en-un-m%c3%a9todo-en-js) que espero pueda resolver tu duda.